# Widgets in recycleview of variable height overlapping (Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

After a question that was answered yesterday, this code can now set the height of the layout/widgets within the recycle view correctly.  However, after 1 or 2 updates to the list, the widgets overlap.  This is vital to my app working and it is super close.

I read in the Kivy documentation that the recycle view reuses widgets, which is why it is more efficient than the scroll view. However, I have not been able to understand what it means by reusing them, or how it may affect my program.

I would encourage anyone, who thinks they may be able to help, to run the code below to get a better understanding of what I have attempted to describe, but any comments, pointers, or solutions will be massively apreciated.

**What currently works:**

- The new layouts that contain widgets are added to the recycle view successfully
- The layouts resize correctly to fit the amount of text they contain

**What doesn't currently work**

- The layouts with widgets moving to the correct position and not overlapping

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior

example_string = 'jshdfjhsdkjfhjkshfjkshjfhsjkdhfkjshfkjshdfjkshjkdfhsjkdhfkjshfjhsjkfhskjhfjkhfkjhdjfkhsjdkhfkjshdkjhsdjhfsjkdhfjkshdjkfhsdkjhfjksdhfkjshdf)£++£(0'

class MASTER(BoxLayout):
    def example_button(self, Button): # Demo of list updating
        global example_string # I know
        example_string += ')+££+(test\n\n\nsdhfsjdgfj)£++£(0'
        temp = []
        id_num = 0
        for post in example_string.split(')+££+('): # The string is an example of the input data
            temp.append({'message_id':id_num, 'text':('[font=Nunito-Bold.ttf][color=161616]Someone:[/color][/font]\n' + post.split(')£++£(')[0]), '_group':str(id_num), '_score':int(post.split(')£++£(')[1])})
            id_num = id_num + 1
        App.get_running_app().posts = temp

class DemoApp(App):
    # One post format = {'message_id':0, 'text':'post_test_here','_size':[0,0], '_group':str(0), '_score':20}
    # Text fromat string = [font=Nunito-Bold.ttf][color=161616]Someone:[/color][/font]\n
    posts = ListProperty([])

    def up_vote(self, button, mode): # Not part of the problem
        if button.state == 'down':
            if mode == 'all':
                print("+1 upvote for message index:" + str(button.parent.parent.message_id) + ' in all posts')
            else:
                print("+1 upvote for message index:" + str(button.parent.parent.message_id) + ' in top posts')
    
    def down_vote(self, button, mode): # Not part of the problem
        if button.state == 'down':
            if mode == 'all':
                print("-1 upvote for message index:" + str(button.parent.parent.message_id) + ' in all posts')
            else:
                print("-1 upvote for message index:" + str(button.parent.parent.message_id) + ' in top posts')





if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

**demo.kv**

```
MASTER:

<MASTER>:
    Button:
        text: 'Add items'
        on_press: root.example_button(self)
    RecycleView:
        viewclass: 'PostGrid'
        scroll_y: 1
        id: rv
        data: app.posts
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            id: box
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            default_size: None, dp(50) #
            size_hint_y: None
            padding: ["10dp", "16dp"]
            spacing: "20dp"
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'

<PostGrid@BoxLayout>:
    message_id: -1
    orientation: "horizontal"
    text: ''
    _group: ''
    _score: 0
    spacing: "6dp"
    text_size: None, None
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    BoxLayout:
        id: voting_menu
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: "2dp"
        size_hint: .2, None
        height: label.height # This binding will force voting_menu to resize.
#        size: self.size # I don't think it has any effect.
        ToggleButton:
            id: button_up
            on_state: app.up_vote(self, 'all')
            group: str(root._group)
            text: "UP"
            color: (1,1,1,1) if self.state=='normal' else (.8,0,0,1)
            font_size: "10dp"
            size_hint: 1, .3
            background_color: .2, .2, .2, 0
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (.1,.1,.1,1)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    radius: [6,]
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: .2,.2,.2,1
                Line:
                    width: 1.4
                    rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, 5)
        Label:
            id: vote_count
            text: str(root._score)
            size_hint: 1, .4
            multiline: False

        ToggleButton:
            id: button_down
            on_state: app.down_vote(self, 'all')
            group: str(root._group)
            text: "DOWN"
            color: (1,1,1,1) if self.state=='normal' else (.8,0,0,1)
            font_size: "10dp"
            size_hint: 1, .3
            background_color: .2, .2, .2, 0
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (.1,.1,.1,1)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    radius: [6,]
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: (.2,.2,.2,1)
                Line:
                    width: 1.4
                    rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, 5)
    Label:
        id: label # For reference.
        text: root.text
        padding: "10dp", "12dp"
        size_hint: .9, None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        font_size: "12dp"
        text_size: self.width, None
        color: 0,0,0,1
        multiline: True
        markup: True
        
#        on_texture_size: app.update_message_size(root.message_id, self.texture_size)

        pos: self.x, self.y

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1)
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: self.texture_size
                radius: [5, 5, 5, 5]
                pos: self.x, self.y
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:0.8,0,0,1
            Line:
                width: 1.4
                rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, 5)
```

**Image of overlap**

[image]

**Guesses**

- Adding items instead of updating all of the items stored in 'posts' at once
- Finding a way to refresh the recycleview to update the widgets
- Creating a custom widget in place of the widgets in layouts for every item in the recycleview

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange problem. I noticed that you are using `self.minimum_height` and `label.height` to try to adjust the size, and I believe your code should work. But it only seems to work sometimes. I have added a hack to work around this problem by setting the `height` of the `PostGrid` instances via python code. Here is that hack:

```
class MASTER(BoxLayout):
    def example_button(self, Button):  # Demo of list updating
        global example_string  # I know
        example_string += ')+££+(test\n\n\nsdhfsjdgfj)£++£(0'
        temp = []
        id_num = 0
        for post in example_string.split(')+££+('):  # The string is an example of the input data
            temp.append({'message_id': id_num, 'text': (
                        '[font=Roboto-Bold.ttf][color=161616]Someone:[/color][/font]\n' + post.split(')£++£(')[0]),
                         '_group': str(id_num), '_score': int(post.split(')£++£(')[1])})
            id_num = id_num + 1
        App.get_running_app().posts = temp
        Clock.schedule_once(self.fix_sizes)
        
    def fix_sizes(self, dt):
        rbl = self.ids.box
        for w in rbl.walk():
            if isinstance(w, Factory.PostGrid):
                w.height = max(w.ids.label.height, w.ids.voting_menu.height)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution.  This worked for adding a few new items, however beyond about 8 of the items in the recycle view a similar issue occurs.  My goal is to be able to add a very large amount and just keep adding.  When you tested this did you have a similar issue, an image showing a similar issue to before https://imgur.com/a/WjqMuyO

Comment: Do you think I may have more luck using scroll view, since it doesn't reuse widgets?  (I don't actually know what it stores it is just still my only guess to what could cause this behavior)

Comment: Yes, I do see that. I hadn't tried clicking more than a couple times.

Comment: `ScrollView` might work. The only reason for using `RecycleView` is if you have a very large number of items in the list (so many that the `ScrollView` gets really slow).

Comment: I've heard that, which is why I used recycle view to start with.  I've just done a brief amount of reading and think it would become a problem in the future if I switched to scroll view.  I'm not entirely sure what to do though if I can't get this to work.